# How to register a type whose constructor takes a Func parameter in Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a class with a constructor that accepts a Func parameter that I need to register with Autofac.

Here's how the class is defined:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  private Func<Task<IProvider<string, object>>> _provider;

  public MyClass(Func<Task<IProvider<string, object>>> provider)
  {
    _provider = provider;
  }

  ...
}
```

How would I register this class with Autofac?

I've tried the following:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>()
  .As<IMyClass>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
  .WithParameter("provider", MyProviderFunc);
```

but this results in the following compilation error:

```
cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'
```

Here's the definition of MyProviderFunc:

```
private static Task<ICRUDProvider<string, object>> MyProviderFunc()
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly convert the method group to a delegate type (otherwise, the compiler has no idea which delegate you want):

```
.WithParameter("provider", new Func<Task<IProvider<string, object>>>(MyProviderFunc));
```